# Which is efficient? Sending multiple parameter to stored procedure or single xml to process from SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

Which is efficient?
Suppose i need to insert values into a single or multiple table from my front-end code, which is better practice? send each parameter one by one to the stored procedure directly and execute it;
or
Use a moderate procedure which accept parameter as xml and execute the required procedure by sending parameter derived from xml; In this case we only sending parameter values the parameter name is kept in moderate function.

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: You should test the two solutions in your environment and measure the performance.

Comment: @SonerGönül I need to know about the security sdvantage also?

Comment: you could also send a datatable to your stored procedure..

Comment: [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). I think it should be a required reading before posting about performance.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect the separate parameter method to perform better.  Not only will that eliminate the XML parsing overhead on the server side, it will also provide a well-defined database interface.

Answer (score 0):

Keep It Simple Stupid mate. That was my answer to one of my devs when reviewing a PR. Passing parameters to a SP is a complete nightmare when you have to read it or find an error. Imagine 15+ parameters in a xml and all the serialisation involved just to return a fixed data structure.
There may be scenarios where this kind of solution is required, but this is not the way to go when you take into consideration how time consuming and costly is developing and maintaining this kind of stored procedures. Tight coupling, scalability are also things to consider.
If your goal is having dynamic parameters in a SP consider this approach:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ReviewSearch]
    @Ids nvarchar(max),
    @Identifiers nvarchar(max),
    @Pnr nvarchar(10),
    @HotelId bigint,
    @PassengerEmail nvarchar(50),
    @ReviewStatus nvarchar(20),
    @Deleted bit = null,
    @CompletedUtcFrom datetime,
    @CompletedUtcTo datetime,
    @HotelStayEndUtcFrom datetime,
    @HotelStayEndUtcTo datetime

AS

    SELECT Id, Identifier, Pnr, DebtorIdentifier, HotelId, PassengerEmail, UserFullName, OverallRating, 
                CreatedUtc, HotelStayStartUtc, HotelStayEndUtc, TravelerNotifId, TravelerNotifSentNumber, TravelerNotifSentUtc, 
                CompletedUtc, ApprovalNotifId, ApprovalNotifSentNumber, ApprovalNotifSentUtc, ApprovedUtc, ApprovedBy, ReviewStatus, Deleted
    FROM     Review
    WHERE  (@Ids IS NULL OR Id IN (SELECT Item FROM Split(@Ids, ','))) AND 
                    (@Identifiers IS NULL OR Identifier IN (SELECT Item FROM Split(@Identifiers, ','))) AND 
                    (@Pnr IS NULL OR Pnr = @Pnr) AND 
                    (@HotelId IS NULL OR HotelId = @HotelId) AND 
                    (@PassengerEmail IS NULL OR PassengerEmail = @PassengerEmail) AND 
                    (@ReviewStatus IS NULL OR ReviewStatus IN (SELECT Item FROM Split(@ReviewStatus, ','))) AND 
                    (@Deleted IS NULL OR Deleted = @Deleted) AND
                    (@CompletedUtcFrom IS NULL OR CompletedUtc >= @CompletedUtcFrom) AND
                    (@CompletedUtcTo IS NULL OR CompletedUtc <= @CompletedUtcTo) AND
                    (@HotelStayEndUtcFrom IS NULL OR HotelStayEndUtc >= @HotelStayEndUtcFrom) AND
                    (@HotelStayEndUtcTo IS NULL OR HotelStayEndUtc <= @HotelStayEndUtcTo)
```